# Windows, настройка vpn + proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, маршрутизация, vpn

Windows Server 2019, настроен vpn клиент,настроен прокси сервер (3proxy). Выход прокси - vpn. Вроде все работат. Но через vpn идет весь трафик, а нужно, чтобы в vpn попадал только тафик от 3proxy. Как такое сделать?

```
ipconfig /all
Настройка протокола IP для Windows

   Имя компьютера  . . . . . . . . . : server1
   Основной DNS-суффикс  . . . . . . : lan
   Тип узла. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Гибридный
   IP-маршрутизация включена . . . . : Нет
   WINS-прокси включен . . . . . . . : Нет
   Порядок просмотра суффиксов DNS . : lan

Адаптер PPP tr17:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : 
   Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : tr17
   Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Нет
   Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
   IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.8.245(Основной) 
   Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.2.1
   NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Отключен

Адаптер Ethernet eth0:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : 
   Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
   Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Нет
   Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
   IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.10.2(Основной) 
   Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . : 10.200.10.1
   DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

route print
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 24...........................tr17
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.200.10.1      10.200.10.2   4506
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.8.245     26
       10.8.8.245  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.8.245    281
      10.200.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.200.10.2   4506
      10.200.10.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2   4506
    10.200.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2   4506
   87.236.161.210  255.255.255.255      10.200.10.1      10.200.10.2   4251
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.200.10.2   4506
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.8.245     26
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2   4506
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.8.245    281
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Сетевой адрес            Маска    Адрес шлюза      Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.200.10.1  По умолчанию 
===========================================================================
```

ЗЫ: ннастройка прокси минимальная, при создании vpn соединения изменял только то, что необходимо для подключения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] для ethernet установил метрику для шлюза 1

[2] для vpn отключил "использовать основной шлюз в удаленной сети"

[3] после установления vpn соединения создать маршрут

`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 metric 2 if 24`

24 - номер интерфейса, можно посмотреть в `route print`

В результате `route print`

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 13...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
 24...........................tr17
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.200.10.1      10.200.10.2     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link       10.8.13.247     27
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         10.8.0.1      10.8.13.247     26
      10.8.13.247  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.8.13.247    281
      10.200.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.200.10.2    281
      10.200.10.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2    281
    10.200.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2    281
   87.236.161.210  255.255.255.255      10.200.10.1      10.200.10.2     26
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.200.10.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.8.13.247    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.200.10.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.8.13.247    281
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Сетевой адрес            Маска    Адрес шлюза      Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.200.10.1       1
===========================================================================
```

Вроде работает, но это не точно ...